# Meteor: How do I check if a collection exists

Tags: meteor

I am using accounts entry, and as you may know, it doesn't allow taking you to separate pages on signup and signin.

So, what I want to do is check if a field called under profile called "avatar" exists. I just want a true or false answer (or null, -1, etc).

How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "profile"? Do you mean the user object (`Meteor.user()`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that will return a boolean indicating if the avatar field exists in the current user's profile:

```js
var hasAvatar = function() {
  var user = Meteor.user();
  return user && user.profile && user.profile.avatar;
};
```

Comment: better without the `var` so it can be globally accessible (by a helper for example)

Answer (score 0):

If its a user collection where all the user data is stored, you can simply do `Meteor.user()` in the browser console and get the data.

If you have stored in some mongo collection than all you got to do is `CollectionName.find().fetch()`

Also if you have avatar field in profile of user collection than you can simple do `Meteor.user().profile.avatar` It will show an object if it exist. :)

try and let me know :)